# Wrong form border is coloured onfocus

Tags: html, css

Here is what I currently have:

```
<script>
function colour(x){
    document.getElementById(x).style.border = "1px green solid";
}
</script>
<p>Email<span style="color:red">*</span><input type="email" name="email" autofocus required/></p>
<p>Name<span style="color:red">*</span><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required onfocus="colour(this.id)"/><span style="color:red">*</span><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required onfocus="colour(this.d)"/></p>
```

No matter what I do it will focus on the email, can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could fix it, with CSS. Just write some CSS like this.

```
input:focus {
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

And your input fields are green bordered if they are in Focus. No Need for JavaScript in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it without JavaScript you have to use [border](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp) along with [outline](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp).

The outline property will disable the browser focus color.

```
input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

> no matter what i do, it focuses on the email

If you want to focus another input field, remove the [autofocus](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) property from your email field and add it to the field you want to focus at page load. If you don't want that a field is focused at page load, just remove the autofocus attribute.